# Dribbble api version 2

Tags: javascript, api

I've used the [v1 of the Dribbble's API](http://developer.dribbble.com/v1/) to show all my shots on my portfolio page. It requires the Client Access Token and nothing more. A few days ago I updated Client Access Token and got the error which says that v1 API is deprecated and I must use the [v2](http://developer.dribbble.com/v2/). I read [the documentaion](http://developer.dribbble.com/v2/) and didn't find any approaches to use the API without OAuth 2.

Is it possible to use updated Dribbble's API without OAuth 2? According to the docs I can't show shots in my portfolio as I did before.

Comment: [You can still list your own shots so long as you authenticate as yourself.](http://developer.dribbble.com/v2/shots)

Comment: @BoltClock How can I authenticate myself without OAuth2?

Comment: That no longer appears to be an option.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe we have to authenticate an admin on the back-end side and then we'll able to use a refresh token to send it to the client side

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use OAuth and if you notice `v1` will be deprecated come March 2018.  At first I was somewhat confused by `v2` documentation in obtaining an `access token` but after spending a little time experimenting I was able to figure out how to get an `access token`.

First you will need to [Register Application](https://dribbble.com/account/applications/new).  Do note what you put in the `Callback URL` because it's important later.

For example, my callback url is `http://grim.com`

Referencing [`OAuth`](http://developer.dribbble.com/v2/oauth/) on my Mac in the terminal I ran a `curl`:

```
curl GET https://dribbble.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID_FROM_APPLICATION
```

After running the `curl` I copied the link returned from the response and ran `open URL` which in the browser I was prompted a sign in.  After sign in I was asked if I wanted accept, then I was redirected to the `Callback URL`.  In the browser copy the last part of the code from the redirect, the URL will look like this:

```
http://grim.com?code=sadhjsahdjksahdjsahdjsahdkjsa
```

After copying the code (`?code=sadhjsahdjksahdjsahdjsahdkjsa`) I opened [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/apps) and changed it to `Post` from `Get`.

I passed:

```
https://dribbble.com/oauth/token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&code=sadhjsahdjksahdjsahdjsahdkjsa
```

I was returned:

```
{
    "access_token":"1323213h23h2131j2h3jk12",
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "scope":"public",
    "created_at":13211421
}
```

Using the token in the terminal we can do:

```
curl "https://api.dribbble.com/v2/user?access_token=1323213h23h2131j2h3jk12"
```

and a return of the `user` should be in the terminal. There might be a better solution out there but hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! We did the same things.
Have you tried to get all shots for a team using v2 API?
I opened a question a few days ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48625093/dribbble-api-v2-get-all-shots-for-the-certain-team

We decided to get all shots for every designer on the back-end side using OAuth tokens and then add our own API which will send all merged shots to client. But I don't think that it is a good idea.

I would appreciate hearing your thoughts on this.